# CDATA in payload factory in WSO2 ESB

Tags: xml, esb, wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to write a sequence in ESB and populate my payload data by using payload factory as i stated below example.

```
  <payloadFactory>
     <format>
        <p:echoInt xmlns:p="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
           <in xmlns="">$1</in>
        </p:echoInt>
     </format>
     <args>
        <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="an-xml-formatted-string"/>
     </args>
  </payloadFactory>
 <send>
     <endpoint>
        <address uri="http://noon101:8280/services/echo" format="soap11"/>
     </endpoint>
  </send>
```

Because my string is formatted as xml when i send this payload to the service, the service tries to parse my xml parameter and (i do not understand what is the exact reason) my web service method is not called. in this [link](http://pomzung.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/treating-xml-input-parameters-of-a-soap-request-as-a-string/) it says that if i use cdata than the parser will not parse my xml formatted string and there will be no problem.

But the problem is Payload Factory mediator do not accept Cdata in its content. When i write the configuration of Payload Factory as indicated below, it deletes CDATA keywords from it and problem consists.

```
  <payloadFactory>
     <format>
        <p:echoInt xmlns:p="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
           <in xmlns=""> <![CDATA[ $1 ]]> </in>
        </p:echoInt>
     </format>
     <args>
        <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="an-xml-formatted-string"/>
     </args>
  </payloadFactory>
```

What would be the solution to this problem? Any other mediator to set payload or any workaround will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use XSLT mediator to that (Payload factory mediator does not support CDATA). But if you use it. And also you need to do the following configuration to preserve CDATA in the mediation flow. [1]

This will be helpful too.
http://tharindumathew.com/2012/05/24/adding-cdata-tags-through-xslt/

[1]http://blog.shelan.org/2013/03/how-to-send-cdata-inside-your-soap.html

Comment: ok i am using xsl transformation, but a new problem is occuring. when i wroto 

                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/*"/>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>

esb disables the &lt etc and transformation get into a weird way.

Comment: This is not an exact and direct solution to my problem but your links were very helpful to solve my problem so i accepted this as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use CDATA inside payload factory mediator. The only thing you need to do is, you need to store the format in registry and use it from there. [Registry Resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAnL8.png)

Following is a sample. In this sample, I am using the response of my previous call as the input for the message I am preparing with payload factory mediator.

```
     <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
               name="ALLRESULTS"
               expression="$body/child::*[fn:position()=1]"
               scope="default"
               type="STRING"/>

     <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format key="conf:/repository/esb/myPF"/>
        <args>
           <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:ALLRESULTS"/>
           <arg value="1"/>
        </args>
     </payloadFactory>
```

The content of the registry resource is as follows.

```
                       <ns:testMethod xmlns:ns="http://example.com">
                            <xs:xmlBody xmlns:xs="http://example.com"><![CDATA[$1]]></xs:xmlBody>
                            <xs:sessionId xmlns:xs="http://example.com">$2</xs:sessionId>
                        </ns:testMethod>
```

With this way, you can use CDATA inside payload factory mediator.

Comment: This is actually the solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass CDATA, You can use XSLT mediator to construct such messages. Payload factory, AFAIK doesn't support CDATA argument.

Comment: I couldn't find any simple resource that sets payload data using xslt transformation in esb, can you recommend some?

Comment: xslt mediator uses xslt script, and you need to write xslt script .XSLt mediator smaples you can find in the ESb documentation

Comment: I tried but it does not work. It gives this error: Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'C' (code 67) (CDATA not allowed in prolog/epilog)