# Not able to evaluate the JSON response data having special Character in wso2

Tags: arrays, json, wso2

I am fetching the data from gmail server and modifying the income response to match our model and below is the XML connector

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="readMail"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property expression="json-eval($.id)" name="id"/>
         <property expression="json-eval($.format)" name="format"/>
         <property expression="json-eval($.metadataHeaders)" name="metadataHeaders"/>
         <gmail.init>
            <userId>pk@gmail.com</userId>
            <refreshToken>1/kjvw78oyrwUR3SOeUUEowA</refreshToken>
            <clientSecret>zSx8GJT44q554</clientSecret>
            <clientId>48015251641-sm4k53u.apps.googleusercontent.com</clientId>
            <accessToken>ya29.HNPGCpInGt5Z</accessToken>
            <apiUrl>https://www.googleapis.com/gmail</apiUrl>
         </gmail.init>
         <gmail.readMail>
            <id>{$ctx:id}</id>
            <format>{$ctx:format}</format>
            <metadataHeaders>{$ctx:metadataHeaders}</metadataHeaders>
         </gmail.readMail>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <jsonArray>
                  <channel>Email</channel>
                  <date_time>$1</date_time>
                  <channel_message>$2</channel_message>
                  <channel_message_ID>$3</channel_message_ID>
                  <created_by>$4</created_by>
               </jsonArray>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.payload.headers[18].value"/>
               <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.snippet"/>
               <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.id"/>
               <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.payload.headers[24].value"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

It works well if we don't play with the income response and the response is

```
{
"id": "15d9882a2083",
"threadId": "15d984cccda1f63b",
"labelIds": [
    "UNREAD",
    "IMPORTANT",
    "CATEGORY_PERSONAL",
    "INBOX"
],
"snippet": "Hello Test, I am waiting for your response. Thanks Kumar 7795821986 From: Pawan, Kumar Sent: Monday, July 31, 2017 4:29 PM To: &#39;kmp@gmail.com&#39; &lt;kmp@gmail.com&gt; Subject:",
"historyId": "2445",
"internalDate": "1501502285000",
"payload": {
    "partId": "",
    "mimeType": "multipart/alternative",
    "filename": "",
    "headers": [
        {
            "name": "Delivered-To", 0
            "value": "kmps@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "Received", 1
            "value": "by 10.182.97.199 with SMTP id ec7csp3710677obb;        Mon, 31 Jul 2017 04:58:06 -0700 (PDT)"
        },
        {
            "name": "X-Received",
            "value": "by 10.84.167.2 with SMTP id c2mr17110575plb.336.1501502286621;        Mon, 31 Jul 2017 04:58:06 -0700 (PDT)"
        },
        {
            "name": "ARC-Seal",
            "value": "i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1501502286; cv=none;        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;        b=n/+kZs18GcQlkEXGX0aQgxMgd9VUgWXoKThXzWCWKXdmlgc8qxvsj4OMGboEnQtQPL         l9VzbkJ9o3TZDTmCi+krVuinmQMrD3APtzosvsYRQ3xoto1DPbUQ0QgLVRnauA9QNaBaIvLvI2OPVIdpy7ESjSfC4wnve/seSSdgN0h5xuzZw3vkVTzsRsiD1Mvn2H1LfanIjzv88/8/o8JRFLxl         KjoQ=="
        },
        {
            "name": "ARC-Message-Signature",
            "value": "i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;        h=mime-version:spamdiagnosticmetadata:spamdiagnosticoutput         :content-language:accept-language:message-id:date:thread-index         :thread-topic:subject:to:from:dkim-signature         :arc-authentication-results;        bh=YpP6f56u11c7PZ8c3cD7kRP5/WQY7G0dC3crOi3Z+LY=;        b=aKZNvlh8Z+oxbt6J3yiZ7        hv6h6s4fAT/ibB3BX2wImb6fCDBuIaoRdO1c6QLvV9m6mh+Rcj/mQfAhpignalmB2IHd         GRhl72dfDHAinr7/uKESKuMUNe6WDCKxOlhT6qEjBZG2JUiAJ+WBldl4Qfk1ZDxTzGIO         1+6kVlgcBlTxVcNeX2BgriW/ekbo64SVW7xzJc/nlHI8IwolAhoYy0qaGymcqpWZbg34         3vkQ=="
        },

        {
            "name": "Return-Path",
            "value": "<Kumar.Pawan@gmail.com>"
        },
         {
            "name": "Received-SPF",
            "value": "pass (google.com: domain of kumar.pawan@gmail.com designates 216.32.181.177 as permitted sender) client-ip=216.32.181.177;"
        },            
        {
            "name": "Received",
            "value": "from DM2PR0707.prod.outlook.com (10.160.246.151) by DMprd07.prod.outlook.com (10.160.246.149) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256) id 15.1.1282.10; Mon, 31 Jul 2017 11:58:05 +0000"
        },
        {
            "name": "Received",
            "value": "from DM2PR0701MB1120.namprd07.prod.outlook.com ([fe80::a093:3faf:5648:ce8c]) by DM2PR0701MB1120.namprd07.prod.outlook.com ([fe80::a093:3faf:5648:ce8c%14]) with mapi id 15.01.1282.023; Mon, 31 Jul 2017 11:58:05 +0000"
        },
        {
            "name": "From", 13
            "value": "\"Pawan, Kumar\" <Kumar.Pawan@gmail.com>"
        },
        {
            "name": "To",
            "value": "\"kmps@gmail.com\" <kmps@gmail.com>"
        },
        {
            "name": "Subject",
            "value": "RE: Testing The Application"
        },
        {
            "name": "Thread-Topic",
            "value": "Testing The Application"
        },
        {
            "name": "Thread-Index",
            "value": "AdMJ6/U2XdgtmEKwRzq9Td+H2hW+sQACDUaQ"
        },
        {
            "name": "Date",
            "value": "Mon, 31 Jul 2017 11:58:05 +0000"
        },
        {
            "name": "Message-ID",
            "value": "<DM2PR0701MB1120326F0CF8DA020E0E9D51120.namprd07.prod.outlook.com>"
        },
        {
            "name": "Accept-Language",
            "value": "en-IN, en-US"
        },
        {
            "name": "Content-Language",
            "value": "en-US"
        },
        {
            "name": "X-MS-Has-Attach",
            "value": "serrrttff"
        },
        {
            "name": "X-MS-TNEF-Correlator",
            "value": "werwerr"
        },            
        {
            "name": "x-originating-ip", 25
            "value": "[249.251.141.1208]"
        },
        {
            "name": "x-ms-publictraffictype",
            "value": "Email"
        },
        {
            "name": "x-microsoft-exchange-diagnostics",
            "value": "1;DM2PR0701MB1118;7:TmcDBJD9ajlXGPZrK+7Ndm78rj+jgvwW2Qstv7LgTbDvfB9cimMen+iYXcEQ0CX+jpOpuHsGUww1a1IRz5w4nDZHSUwWI59LksydNMIiYX8FYfuWLiDQ7iABcOJwWFR7ehcVl+ilZL8DM5imk6agJZvRaujZyoaUY="
        },
        {
            "name": "x-ms-office365-filtering-correlation-id",
            "value": "d667a587a-4fa9-08d4d80b6759"
        },
        {
            "name": "x-microsoft-antispam",
            "value": "UriScan:;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(300000500095)(300135000095)(135200095)(300000505095)(300135600095)(300000506095)(300135500095);SRVR:DM2PR0701MB1118;"
        },
        {
            "name": "x-ms-traffictypediagnostic", 30
            "value": "DM2PR0701MB18:"
        },
        {
            "name": "x-exchange-antispam-report-test",
            "value": "UriScan:(2174852155);"
        },
        {
            "name": "x-microsoft-antispam-prvs",
            "value": "<DM2PR0701MB1118CCF26D1E3309721A714899B20@DM2PR0701MB1118.namprd.com>"
        },
        {
            "name": "x-exchange-antispam-report-cfa-test",
            "value": "BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(100000700101)(100105000095)(100000701101)(100105300095)(100000702101)(100105100095)(6040450)(601004)(2401047)(100000805101)(100110500095);SRVR:DM2PR0701MB1118;"
        },
        {
            "name": "x-forefront-prvs",
            "value": "03853D523D"
        },
        {
            "name": "x-forefront-antispam-report",35
            "value": "SFV:NSPM;SFS:(10009020)(6009001)(39450400003)(39840400002)(398(5250100002)(9686003)(55016002)(189998001)(99286003)(1411001)((5001);DIR:OUT;SFP:1101;SCL:1;SRVR:DM2PR0701MB1118;H:DM2PR0701MB1120.namprd07.prod.outlook.com;FPR:;SPF:None;PTR:InfoNoRecords;A:1;MX:1;LANG:en;"
        },

        {
            "name": "spamdiagnosticmetadata",
            "value": "NPM"
        },
        {
            "name": "Content-Type",
            "value": "multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_000_DM2PR0701MB1120326F0CF8DA0299B20DM2PR0701MB1120_\""
        },
        {
            "name": "MIME-Version",
            "value": "1.0"
        },
        {
            "name": "X-OriginatorOrg", 41
            "value": "gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-originalarrivaltime",
            "value": "31 Jul 2017 11:58:05.4191 (UTC)"
        },
        {
            "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-fromentityheader",
            "value": "Hosted"
        },
        {
            "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-id",
            "value": "8d894c2b-238f-490b-8dd1-d93898c5bf83"
        },
        {
            "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped",  45
            "value": "DM2PR0701MB18"
        }
    ],
    "body": {
        "size": 0
    },
    "parts": [
        {
            "partId": "0",
            "mimeType": "text/plain",
            "filename": "",
            "headers": [
                {
                    "name": "Content-Type",
                    "value": "text/plain; charset=\"us-ascii\""
                },
                {
                    "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
                    "value": "quoted-printable"
                }
            ],
            "body": {
                "size": 309,
                "data": "SGVsbG8gVGVzdCwNCg0KSSBhbSB3YWl0aW5nIGZvciB5b3VyIHJlc3BvbnNlLg0KDQpUaGFua3MNClBhd2gZ2xhZCB0aGF0IHlvdSBjYW1lIHRvIG1lZXQgbWUuDQoNCg0KVGhhbmtzDQpQYXdhbiBLdW1hcg0KNzc5NTgyMTk4Ng0K"
            }
        },
        {
            "partId": "1",
            "mimeType": "text/html",
            "filename": "",
            "headers": [
                {
                    "name": "Content-Type",
                    "value": "text/html; charset=\"us-ascii\""
                },
                {
                    "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
                    "value": "quoted-printable"
                }
            ],
            "body": {
                "size": 3360,
                "data": "PGh0bWwgeG1sbnM6dj0idXJuOnNjaubWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbS9vZmZpY2UvMjAwNC8xMi9vbW1sIiB4bE6MiA0IDUgMyA1IDQgNiAzIDIgNDt9DQpAZm9udC1mYWNlDQoJe2ZvbnQtZmFtaWx5OkNhbGlicmk7"
            }
        }
    ]
},
"sizeEstimate": 12167
```

}

The problem is the moment i tried to convert the income response to my model and the request for that particular field starts with special character. It starts giving error. 
For example i want created_by to be value of "Return-Path". But since it starts with special character it gives error < is missing in the backed.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding CDATA to your payload factory to "escape" this <> ?

```html
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
       <jsonArray>
          <channel>Email</channel>
          <date_time>$1</date_time>
          <channel_message>$2</channel_message>
          <channel_message_ID>$3</channel_message_ID>
          <created_by><![CDATA[$4]]></created_by>
       </jsonArray>
    </format>
    <args>
       <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.payload.headers[18].value"/>
       <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.snippet"/>
       <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.id"/>
       <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.payload.headers[24].value"/>
    </args>
 </payloadFactory>
```

Comment: Not able to save <![CDATA[$4]]> in the xml. The moment i save it disappear

Comment: According to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689272/cdata-in-payload-factory-in-wso2-esb/16691651#16691651 it seems that if you store your payload factory format in the registry it is working.

Comment: Its not working, i placed like this <created_by>&lt;![CDATA[$4]]&gt;</created_by>                                                                                        
 and the value which i want to read {
                "name": "From",
                "value": "\"Pawan, Kumar\" <Kumar.Pawan@gmail.com>"
            },