# WSO2 ESB/EI : How to get Original JSON body into XML Payload

Tags: wso2, cdata, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm implementing WSO2 EI-6.4.0 for the project and I want to convert JSON to XML.
Below issue came when HTML tags contain in the JSON response.

Example:

**Input:**

```
{
  "departurePoint": "1: Galle, Sri Lanka<br />2: Hikkaduwa, Sri Lanka<br />3: Unawatuna, Sri Lanka<br />4: Ahangama, Sri Lanka<br />5: Midigama Beach, Sri Lanka<br />6: Weligama, Sri Lanka<br />7: Mirissa, Sri Lanka<br /><br>Traveler pickup is offered<br/>Free Pick up locations : Hikkaduwa , Galle ,Unawatuna , Ahangama , Midigama , Weligama , Mirissa<br><br>"
}
```

**Original Output:**

```
<departurePoint>
    1: Galle, Sri Lanka
    <br />2: Hikkaduwa, Sri Lanka
    <br />3: Unawatuna, Sri Lanka
    <br />4: Ahangama, Sri Lanka
    <br />5: Midigama Beach, Sri Lanka
    <br />6: Weligama, Sri Lanka
    <br />7: Mirissa, Sri Lanka
    <br />
    <br>Traveler pickup is offered
        <br/>Free Pick up locations : Hikkaduwa , Galle ,Unawatuna , Ahangama , Midigama , Weligama , Mirissa
        <br>
    <br>
</departurePoint>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<departurePoint>
    <![CDATA[1: Galle, Sri Lanka<br />2: Hikkaduwa, Sri Lanka<br />3: Unawatuna, Sri Lanka<br />4: Ahangama, Sri Lanka<br />5: Midigama Beach, Sri Lanka<br />6: Weligama, Sri Lanka<br />7: Mirissa, Sri Lanka<br /><br>Traveler pickup is offered<br/>Free Pick up locations : Hikkaduwa , Galle ,Unawatuna , Ahangama , Midigama , Weligama , Mirissa<br><br>]]>
</departurePoint>
```

I couldn't find the way to insert CDATA for the sequence.

Comment: You need to use the XSLT mediator to add CDATA.
Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689272/cdata-in-payload-factory-in-wso2-esb)

Comment: I need this change before it comes to XSLT mapping stage. For XSLT, it comes with converted XML as mentioned above “Original Output” I tried with java script. But couldn’t get proper way to handle.

Comment: You checked this sample [https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI6xx/Sample+440%3A+Converting+JSON+to+XML+Using+XSLT]

Comment: It's not working. "The page you were trying to reach could not be found."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve your requirement, you can use the Payload factory mediator as well. Following is a sample mediation to achieve your requirements. Here a registry resource is used with the CDATA element to avoid a limitation in the payload factory mediator

**Proxy configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="sampleProxy"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <http uri-template="http://www.mocky.io/v2/5dbdc767330000678f16a289"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <log level="custom">
            <property expression="$body/jsonObject/departurePoint" name="test"/>
         </log>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format key="conf:/test/format.xml"/>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body/jsonObject/departurePoint"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

**Registry resource (format.xml)**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap:Body>
     <departurePoint ><![CDATA[$1]]></departurePoint>
</soap:Body>
```

Even with this configuration, you will not get the expected output. The reason for this is WSO2 EI uses STAX parser and by default, the STAX parser is in non-coalescing mode. To correct that, you need to do the following

1. create a file called XMLInputFactory.properties inside `<EI_HOME>`
2. Add the following content into the file

*javax.xml.stream.isCoalescing=false*

Comment: After putting javax.xml.stream.isCoalescing=false, All issues were resolved. No need to add CDATA. Thanks a lot.